# repeat webrtc ICE flow with custom server

Tags: ip, webrtc, nat

I don't completely understand how NAT mapping work, but simple case:

1. Created simple http server binded to 0.0.0.0:8080
2. Tried locally - ok
3. `curl ip.me` returns my NAT ip
4. Try to access server using discovered ip - failed to connect

But webrtc stuff works with my router, so i guess i miss some ports mapping things

So, generally, how to discover how to access my 0.0.0.0:8080 via public IP?

I've try to access my server using $(`curl ip.me`):8080